# nDisplay like funcion/add-on for Blender?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I've been scouring the internet and haven't found anything yet.

Is there a function/add-on in Blender that can send out a clean picture of the viewport real time using Eevee? I mentioned nDisplay in the title because UE4 can do that and even more (multiple monitors + stitching)

So far, I've been able to open a separate window in Blender, full screen the window, toggle fullscreen area, and hide Gizmos/Overlay. I'm even able to lock the camera to view port via the home key which allows me to add the proper lens distortion + depth of field. However, is this the best route? Is there a better way?

Comment: What do you not like about your approach?

Comment: Great question! (Apologies for my delayed response)

What I need is the ability for the virtual camera to perfectly align with the real camera via field of view, position, rotation, and depth of field in real time.